# Codeigniter: Trying to run a query within a loop in the View

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a page that displays posts and I want to get the name of the author next to each post. There is a DB table for pages (with a column called **title** and **author**) and one for authors (with a column called **id** and **author**).

Control

```
function pages() {
  // QUERIES
  $pages_query = $this->db->get('table_pages');
  $authors_query = $this->db->get_where('table_authors', array('id =' => $row->author));

  // DATA
  $data['pages'] = $pages_query;
  $data['authors'] = $authors_query;

  // CREATE
  $this->load->view('admin_pages', $data);
}
```

View

```
    <? foreach ($pages->result() as $row): ?>
         Title: <?=$row->title?>, by <?=$authors['id']?><br />
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

I think my issue is in calling the author based on the id in control but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I think you need join tables, is ther author_id column in table_pages  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to `JOIN` the two tables, so you can access the author names directly, you don't need to use two queries for that...

You want to do something like:

```
function pages() {
    // QUERIES
    $this->db->join('table_authors', 'table_pages.table_authors_id = table_authors.id');
    $pages_query = $this->db->get('table_pages');

    // DATA
    $data['pages'] = $pages_query;

    // CREATE
    $this->load->view('admin_pages', $data);
}
```

View

```
<? foreach ($pages->result() as $row): ?>
     Title: <?=$row->title?>, by <?=$row->table_authors_name?><br />
<? endforeach; ?>
```

You might have to adjust some column names, as I don't know your database structure. If both table_pages and table_authors contain `name` or `title` fields, you'll have to rename the columns in your query. You can do this using

`$this->db->select('table_authors.title AS author_name, ...');`

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. The JOIN Active Record Class doesn't have very good documentation on the CI site and I've been trying to avoid using in-line queries as a practice.

Comment: The Active Record class is nothing more than a set of wrappers to write SQL queries. If you're uncertain of how to do something with Active Record, try figuring out how to do it with pure SQL. A better understanding of (My)SQL will help you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a very simple way, just write the query, get the data and pass it to the view loading function.

```
  For controller you can write like this

       function pages() {

   $pages_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_authors as a INNER JOIN table_pages as p ON a.id=p.table_authors_id");

   // DATA
   $data['pages'] = $pages_query->result_array();


  // CREATE
  $this->load->view('admin_pages', $data); // Passing the data to the view loading function.
   }


 For Views You can write like this.

    <?php
    foreach($pages as $page):
    echo "Title: ".$page['title'].", by ".$page['table_authors_id'];
    endforeach; 
    ?>
```